# Monitor Application logs as part of Jenkins

Tags: c#, .net, iis, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a CI server using Jenkins which builds the code, starts the server, and runs the application tests.  I would like to monitor the logs during this process to check for errors (e.g., "ERROR").  I see a [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) for jenkins but that only seems to monitor the console logs.

I would like something that goes against my application log.  In my particular case I'm using a .NET Server (IIS/C#/ASP).  Maybe I just need a utility specific to my architecture and run a command line interface in Jenkins. Or should I just be using a cloud service for this to monitor my application logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Text-finder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) plugin can parse any files and change the build status if your search matches.

I'm not sure it will solve your issue if you want to do some live monitoring on running applications.

But if you launch this job every minutes, it will do the job :)